# What does `cabal run` do?

Tags: cabal

I would assume `cabal run` does the same thing as doing `cabal repl` and running `:main` in the shell, but in my project, they're doing different things. `cabal repl -> :main` is working correctly in throwing an error I'm trying to test, whereas `cabal run` isn't throwing the same error. Is there something I'm missing?

EDIT: Code sample

```
main = do
    checkFormat [[1,2]] `seq` return () -- force eval

checkFormat :: [[Int]] -> IO ()
checkFormat matrix = all (\row -> checkRow row `seq` True) matrix `seq` return ()

checkRow :: [Int] -> IO ()
checkRow row = error "Test"
```

Running this code with `cabal run` finished the program, while `cabal repl -> :main` errors with `*** Exception: Test`.

EDIT:
So the code sample apparently works... see my actual code at http://github.com/brandonchinn178/sudoku. If you do `cabal run` and input `........a` as the first line, it doesn't error, but if you do `cabal repl -> :main -> ........a` as the first line, it does error

Comment: AFAIK `cabal run` will compile and run your program using your local sandbox, etc (if you have one) - so there is a difference between the two - can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Doesn't `cabal repl` do that as well? I do have a sandbox initialized. I'll put up a code sample above

Comment: are you sure that there is not `Test` on your output somewhere when you run it? (It surely is when I had a quick test, although I am on ghc 7.8.3 right now and I have to admit that I did not setup a `.cabal` just for this)

Comment: @Carsten hm now the code sample works, but my code still doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

From `cabal run --help`:

> Runs the specified executable-like component (an executable, a test, or a
> benchmark), first ensuring it is up to date.

Running here means executing a compiled executable. But as [the GHC documentation says](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/8.8.1/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#loading-compiled-code):

> When you load a Haskell source module into GHCi, it is normally converted to byte-code and run using the interpreter.

So it makes indeed a difference whether you use `cabal run` or GHCi. The most notable difference is performance. GHCi will usually be slower to run, but faster to compile (because it is only compiled to interpretable code).

In your case, strictness seems to be different. I'm not sure why that is. Maybe GHC optimizes away the constants in your program?